# Refresh Excel connections using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have the below code that opens a spreadsheet, deletes all connections and "Saves" a new file.

```
$a = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$a.Visible = $false
$b = $a.Workbooks.Open("F:\Scripts\All Users.xlsx")

do
{
    $b.Connections.Item(1).Delete()
    $Count = $b.Connections.Count()
} until($Count -eq 0)

$b.SaveAs("F:\Scripts\Users Home Drive Search.xlsx")
$b.Close()
```

I would like to know two things:

1. How do I get the sheet to RefreshAll connections? I've tried "$b.Connections.refreshall()" but the refreshall() doesn't exist.
2. How do I quit Excel application? I ran "New-Object -COM "Excel.Application" | Get-Member -MemberType Methods" and I don't see a quit or exit method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RefreshAll()` is a method of the [WorkBook object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.refreshall), so use that to refresh the external connections:

```
$b.RefreshAll()
```

To exit Excel and remove the used COM objects from memory, use

```
$a.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($b)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($a)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

BTW, I would use more descriptive variable names, so `$excel` instead of `$a` and `$workbook` instead of `$b` to avoid confusion later on.